# How to return the sum of one column but only if it matches another

Tags: database, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOrq3iNhviJeOxRuiK6xaSlRWahku4rePp_FFV0j_sE/edit?usp=sharing

So I have all my data in columns A to E, I wish to create a table where it outputs the unique pin numbers, then sums the Net Adj and Cost Net for each unique PIN but I want it to output this data for each reason. This is only a sample of all the data, the full data is about 61,000 rows and goes back from today to 1st of March. In an ideal world I'd also like to be able to restrict the data to a chosen time period.

```
PIN         Reason                   Create Date        Net Adj   Cost Net
105151340   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 00:52:00  2  £6.80
105151340   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 00:53:00  1  £3.40
108521561   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 01:25:00  1  £10.36
105151340   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 02:08:00  1  £3.40
109654104   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 02:08:00  1  £7.35
109654104   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 02:25:00  1  £7.35
105151340   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 02:31:00  6  £20.40
104761891   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 03:16:00  1  £30.95
112999891   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 03:21:00  1  £2.92
112429565   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 03:37:00  2  £11.64
111659318   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 04:12:00  5  £41.10
105151340   42 (+)or(-) due to cycle count  01/05/2023 02:31:00  5  £20.40
110558099   3 Picking Error                 01/05/2023 04:47:00  1  £8.74
110771025   42 (+)or(-) due to cycle count  01/05/2023 06:40:00 -1  -£7.35
105696016   42 (+)or(-) due to cycle count  01/05/2023 06:41:00  1  £8.91
110462046   42 (+)or(-) due to cycle count  01/05/2023 06:49:00 14  £165.19
112671212   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 08:36:00  5  £3.73
104809066   3 (+)/(-) due to picking        01/05/2023 09:02:00  1  £8.82
108217367   1 Waste                         01/05/2023 09:12:00 -3  -£57.44
108210801   1 Waste                         01/05/2023 09:12:00 -2  -£33.14
111538655   1 Waste                         01/05/2023 09:12:00 -5  -£89.95
```

So I have already got the list of Unique PINs, that was just a =UNIQUE(A2:A).
And I messed around a little bit with SUMPRODUCT and INDEX and MATCH formuals but didn't really get anywhere. I was thinking it would maybe need a QUERY forumla but I don't know enough about the QUERY formula and how to use it.

I have filled out one of the rows in the table I wish the data to output into but I did that just by eye and as an example. This is in the sheet which I have linked.
[Example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqFIi.png)

I didn't even attempt the matter of restricting it to a specific time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

**Net Adj**

```cpp
=MAP($H3:$H,LAMBDA(pin,IF(pin="",,SUMIFS($D2:$D,$A2:$A,pin,$B2:$B,I1))))
```

**Cost Net**

```cpp
=MAP($H3:$H,LAMBDA(pin,IF(pin="",,SUMIFS($E2:$E,$A2:$A,pin,$B2:$B,I1))))
```

With the `I1` reference adjusted accordingly.

Here we are using [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) to iterate over each `pin` using a single formula instead of dragging the formula across.

Comment: This works well thank you, any thoughts on whether the "42 (+)or(-) due to cycle count" could be split into 2 columns, one to sum the positive adjustments and one to show the negative?

Comment: can you show an example of how this would look like in your sample sheet?

Comment: I have done an example on the first sheet, and added some extra made up entries for PIN 105151340

Comment: @OwenClinch, you can just add another condition inside the SUMIFS. `SUMIFS(range,">0")` for gain and `"<0"` for loss.